# What are the specific degrees of freedom of a Chi-squared Goodness of Fit test?

Tags: distributions, chi-squared-test, goodness-of-fit, degrees-of-freedom

Several references specify df (degree of freedom) values differently for each distribution. I also took a look at these posts ([1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/35021/what-are-the-degrees-of-freedom-of-a-distribution), [2](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16921/how-to-understand-degrees-of-freedom), [3](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14458/degrees-of-freedom-for-chi-squared-test)), but they don't seem to address my problem directly.

From what I know so far, the df for a $\chi^2$-Goodness of Fit test should be $k-m$ where $k$ is the number of items included in the calculation of the $\chi^2$ value and $m$ is the number of quantities in the distribution function used to calculate the expected values [Ref. *Miller and Freund's Probability and Statistics for Engineers*]. There are other references that specify this as $k-m-1$ like in the Wikipedia page on [Goodness-of-Fit testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodness_of_fit). I just don't know what to take.

My question is specifically what would be the df to use in the following distributions for a $\chi^2$-Goodness of Fit test?

- Binomial distribution
- Poisson distribution
- Normal distribution
- Exponential distribution
- Uniform distribution

Comment: Ir depends on what, *exactly* you're doing to conduct these tests. Personally, I'd avoid using a chi-square to test goodness of fit for any of these distributions; its power is terrible.

Comment: Yes, I understand, @Glen_b, but I do need to know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Miller and Freund actually specify that their $m$ is "the number of quantities obtained *from the observed data* that are needed to calculate the expected frequencies" (8th ed, p296). The difference from what you *said* that they say is critical, since the total count is something you calculate from the data.

Now if you look at their examples, the total count is included in $m$ quite explicitly (there's an example on the very same page they define their $m$ on).

The ones that specify $k-m-1$ define $m$ in a way that *doesn't* include the total count.

Which is to say, when you look properly, everyone agrees, since their definitions of $m$ differ by 1 in just the right way that they both give the same result. [I'd never read the text before I looked just now, it's *easy* to find what they say and verify it by reading an example to check.]

So all you need to do now is figure out how many parameters you estimate in each case and then include the 1 in the appropriate place for whichever formula you use (and that number of parameters is NOT always the same even if you test for the same distribution; testing a Poisson(10) is not the same as testing a Poisson with unspecified $\lambda$). Just count how many parameters you estimate, then add 1 when you use the total count.

So for example, if you estimate both parameters of the normal, you'd normally subtract 3 d.f. from the number of groups. If both parameters are specified, you'd only subtract 1. If you estimate one parameter, you'd subtract 2, and so on.

---

[Why do Miller and Freund give the formula differently from almost everyone else? I'd say it's because there are cases for goodness of fit where you *don't* match on the total sample size to estimate parameters, and so you don't subtract that 1. One goodness of fit example (but not a goodness-of-distributional-fit example) occurs when you test whether a standard mortality table applies to some sample, where the expected count is determined by the mortality rates and the exposure. By Miller and Freund's approach, you wouldn't be led to erroneously subtract an extra 1 from the d.f.]

---

However - and this is a pretty big caveat, which quite a few books get wrong -  those formulas actually only apply when the parameters are estimated from the grouped data. If you estimate parameters from ungrouped data (e.g. you calculate mean and variance of a supposedly normal sample, then split it into bins for testing for normality) then you [don't have a $\chi^2$ distribution at all](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/71871/impact-of-data-based-bin-boundaries-on-a-chi-square-goodness-of-fit-test/73120#73120).

On the other hand, the distribution function will lie between that of a $\chi^2_{k-1}$ and $\chi^2_{k-m-1}$ (where here $m$ *doesn't* include the total count), so you can at least get bounds on the p-value; alternatively you could use simulation to get a p-value. In the R package the `pearson.test` function in package `nortest` offers both ($k-m-1$ is the default, but you can get the other bound with a change of a default argument).

[On the other, other hand, it would seem crazy to throw away information by estimating the parameters badly just in order to get a chi-square; better to go to the small effort of simulating. On the [*gripping hand*](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=On+The+Gripping+Hand), nobody has any business testing goodness of fit using a chi-square test in any case so this is all moot. As I said in comments, its power is terrible. Indeed in many practical cases the bias is so bad you'd often be better off [rolling a 20-sided die](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/01/20-sided_die.jpg) and rejecting the null on a 1. I wish that were a joke. Even where the power exceeds the significance level, the power may often still be so low you might as well stick with the die roll.]

Comment: Thanks for the intuition. I can understand the need for the $\chi^2$ test; this is not the testing of hypothesis concerning means and variances. I am clear at defining df for $\chi^2$ for testing variances and test of independence.  Specifically, I require the df for verifying whether the given sample set follows the claimed distribution -- the Goodness of Fit test.

Comment: @ÉbeIsaac I *only* discuss the chi-square goodness of fit test in my answer. If you think that I discuss anything else at any point then you've misunderstood what I am telling you.

Comment: Yes, Glen, that was *before* you made the extensive series of edits. Could you just explain a little more with this example: a sample set of $n$ items that is claimed to follow normal distribution (null hypothesis) with $\mu$ and $\sigma$ specified. How to fix the df for this test in a $\chi^2$ goodness of fit test and what would be the critical(rejection) region?

Comment: At no point during my editing was it about anything but the goodness of fit test. If your $\mu$ and $\sigma$ are specified you aren't estimating them, so they count as zero parameters estimated from data (obviously). Consequently, you only have the $-1$ from using the total count to estimate the expected counts. The rejection region is always upper tail but its value depends on the degrees of freedom, which is $n-1$ in this case.

Comment: Great. Could you give an example that would have $m$ as two?

Comment: If you're not asking me to supply a fully worked example then you would need to clarify what you mean. If you just want an example of a case where it would happen that m=2, a normal where you only have the grouped data and the parameters aren't specified. If you are asking for a fully worked example, then that's a substantial change to the question that was asked after it was answered, and I decline to do that.

Comment: I just meant that I want a simple case for m=2 like what I asked for m=0 in the comments.

Comment: I don't know what that means. Is my second sentence above "*If you just want an example of a case where it would happen that m=2 ....*" what you wanted?

Comment: Not a whole Q/A solution, but just the example case as in my previous comment.

Comment: Please answer the explicit question I asked in my last comment. The comment it refers to (4 above this one) contains the example case  "*a normal where you only have the grouped data and the parameters aren't specified*". Either that's sufficient or it isn't. Please be clear about whether it is or not, and if not, why not.

Comment: Yes, that is true, the normal with no parameters specified would mean m=2. I just needed some clarifications: when only one of $\mu$ or $\sigma$ is known, would df = $n-2$, and when no parameter is given then df = $n-3$ in a normal distributed sample set?

Comment: Yes, correct. There's an example of both fully specified and estimated  parameters (from the grouped data) cases [here](http://www.real-statistics.com/tests-normality-and-symmetry/statistical-tests-normality-symmetry/chi-square-test-for-normality/). It uses Excel.

Comment: Thank you. Correct me if I'm wrong: so $m$ in $n=k-m-1$ would stand for no. of unknown parameters in the distribution that the sample set is claimed to follow. Right?

Comment: Yes. And when the formula is $k-m$, this $m$ is generally 1 larger than the number of unknown parameters.

Comment: Wonderful. Answer accepted! It would be nice if you could summarise our discussion in your answer. I'm sure there would be many others who would benefit from this post.